# How to create a folder using alfresco-api

Tags: alfresco

I want to create a folder using ALFRESCO API, so I used this function:

```
public Folder createFolder(String parentFolderId, String folderName) {
    Session cmisSession = getCmisSession();
    Folder rootFolder = (Folder) cmisSession.getObject(parentFolderId);

    Folder subFolder = null;
    try {
        // Making an assumption here that you probably wouldn't normally do
        subFolder = (Folder) cmisSession.getObjectByPath(rootFolder.getPath() + "/" + folderName);
        System.out.println("Folder already existed!");
    } catch (CmisObjectNotFoundException onfe) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("cmis:objectTypeId",  "cmis:folder");
        props.put("cmis:name", folderName);
        subFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(props);
        String subFolderId = subFolder.getId();
        System.out.println("Created new folder: " + subFolderId);
    }

    return subFolder;
}
```

this folder was created in `documentLibrary`.
I do not know how to create another folder inside this new folder.

PS: this function is the one that is defined in `alfresco-api-examples`

Comment: Did you try following any Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS examples? If not, what happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

The function you reference is an example helper function that will return a CMIS Folder object given the parent folder ID and folder name. If the folder does not exist, it will create a new folder and return that.

For example, if you have a folder structure like documentLibrary/folder1 and you call createFolder(documentLibraryId, "folder1") you will get a CMIS Folder object back that represents the "folder 1" folder.

If you were to call createFolder(documentLibraryId, "folder2") the folder would not be found, a new folder named "folder2" would be created, and the code would return a CMIS Folder object that represents the new "folder 2" folder.

Now that you have a CMIS Folder object, you can invoke its methods. If you want to create a new folder you can either call createFolder again, but this time pass in the new Folder's ID, like this:

```
Folder subFolder = createFolder(folder.id, "subfolder");
```

or you can use the CMIS Folder object's createFolder method, but you'll have to pass in a properties object, like this

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "subfolder");
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");

Folder subFolder = folder.createFolder(properties);
```

For more OpenCMIS code examples, see https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/create-objects/index.html